# Signature acquire point pressure time android

Tags: android, point, signature, pressure

my problem is that i would acquire a signiture from screen in app android.I would that the signature is composed from succession of points, of these I want the coordinate x and y, pressure on the screen and the time interval between the points. For the coordinate there is a class in android but i don't found how to calcolate also other two parameters. You know some class in android ?

Answer (score 0):

The `MotionEvent` class is the one you need. An object of this class is provided to you in the `onTouchEvent` function of the `View` class. Simply overload this function to implement the behaviour you want for your app.